# How can I initialize javascript array with values from a database using yii?

Tags: javascript, arrays, yii2

I have to create a javascript array whose elements are hard coded but I want to fetched their elements from database . Is it possible? If so, how?
here is my code

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var array = ["../Images/stu_9.png", "../Images/stu_9.png", "../Images/stu_9.png", "../Images/stu_9.png"];
for( i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="'+array[i]+'">');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: So you're asking how to get the image locations from a field in your database, and pass them to `var array`? You need to write them to the DOM before you can access them. You also have duplicate `ID`s, and shouldn't really use the word `array` as a variable name as it's contiguous with the name `Array`.

Comment: please elaborate your answer where can I write Document Object Model ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the image paths saved in a field in your database, you need to write them to the DOM before you can access them. This would be done by **echoing** the variables to the page itself. If you don't want these file paths to be visible to visitors, you can **hide** them with CSS.

```
<?php

$image_paths = []; // An array containing your image paths, retrieved from the database

echo "<div id='images'>";
foreach($image_paths as $image_path) {
  echo "<div>" . $image_path . "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

This will give you:

```
<div id="images">
  <div>../Images/stu_9.png</div>
  <div>../Images/stu_10.png</div>
  <div>../Images/stu_11.png</div>
</div>
```

And so on.

You can then hide this, so it isn't displayed to visitors, but is still visible in the DOM:

```
#images {
  display: none;
}
```

You can then **target** this invisible DOM with your JavaScript:

```js
var images_array = [];
var images = document.getElementById('images');

for (var i = 0; i < images.children.length; i++) {
  images_array.push(images.children[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(images_array);
```

```css
#images {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <div>../Images/stu_9.png</div>
  <div>../Images/stu_10.png</div>
  <div>../Images/stu_11.png</div>
</div>
```

Also note that in your above code, you have duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup. Also, you shouldn't really use the word `array` as a variable name as it's contiguous with the name `Array`. I've replaced it with `images_array` in my example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: but how can I retrieved images path from database in an array??
this code is not working
<?php

$image_paths = []; // An array containing your image paths, retrieved from the database

echo "<div id='images'>";
foreach($image_paths as $image_path) {
  echo "<div>" . $image_path . "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";

?><script>
var images_array = [];
var images = document.getElementById('images');

for (var i = 0; i < images.children.length; i++) {
  images_array.push(images.children[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(images_array);
</script>

Comment: I am unsure of the **exact** configuration of your database (and connection method), but considering you are using Yii, you can use something like `$array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('images')->from('table')->queryAll();`. See [**this page**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) for more information. Once you get your information into the array, the above **will** work (as is proven in the example).

Comment: After adding your above code this give an error
"Calling unknown method: yii\db\Command::select()"

$image_paths = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->select('Car_Image')
    ->from('register_car')
    ->queryAll();

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use client side script for this.Follow below steps
  1. Get an array of images path from database in controller action.
  2 Render this array on view part.
  3. Write client side script in your view file i.e. $this->registerJs("script code here");
```

Here is complete code for your view file :

```
<?php
$this->registerJs('var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var array = '.$arr_Images_From_controller.';
for( i=0; i<array.length; i++){
container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img src="/'+array[i]+/'">");
}');
?>
```